# Error in Pushing a TableViewCell to Another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5.1

I trying to pass the data from TableViewCell to the another ViewController.But No data Displaying in the another ViewController.here is my Code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


   PeripheralManager *objSelected=[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   [self prepareForSegue:@"TableDetails" sender:objSelectedDevice];
 }


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TableDetails"])
   {


   DetailViewController *detail=segue.destinationViewController;
   detail.dataArray=device;
   }

 }
```

Error Message

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-10-24 12:01:39.805 [3182:707] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-10-24 12:01:40.164 [3182:707] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-10-24 12:01:40.167 [3182:707] Finishing up a get navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might corrupted.
```

Comment: Looks like you are calling the seque twice. Have you set it in the Storyboard **as well** as in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your extra code Only do this-

In `DetailViewController.h`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

In `DetailViewController.m`

```
@synthesize dataArray = _dataArray;
```

Now In `TableViewController.m` Just write this -

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TableDetails"])
   {
     DetailViewController *detailViewObject = segue.destinationViewController;
     detailViewObject.dataArray = anyArray;
   }
}
```

Here I'm passing `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mdc animated:YES];
```

That is what `Segue` will do automatically

Also, you are having 3 lines that will load view controller - see below for comments:

```
NSInteger row=[indexPath row];
NSString *value=[device objectAtIndex:row];
MeBleDetailViewController *mdc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MeBleDetailViewController"];  
mdc.deviceName=value;
[self presentModalViewController:mdc animated:YES];    // Load ViewController
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    // Load ViewController
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mdc animated:YES];   // Load ViewController
```

That is why you are getting that error: **nested push** animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

Also, If you have configured the segue from table cell to another view controller then you don't need anything in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

---

Edit:

Whatever data you want the pushed view controller to have - put it in `prepareforSegue` method instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

If you create a segue from table cell to view controller then you don't need to execute the following as this method is to execute the segue programmatically.

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check for those 3 lines and see which one you really require.

Comment: yes correct.what is meant by Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Comment: if possible edit my coding because still I'm having same error

Comment: No data Dispaly in the anothe ViewController and Back is also making problem if i pressed two times then only goes to main ViewController

Comment: Can you show what changes you made? Also, have you configured the segue from table cell to another view controller?

Comment: Could you please explain - `How did you configure the segue?`

Comment: i passed the data to another ViewController through segue.

Comment: What I mean is did you use ctrl + drag from your table cell to another view controller? How did you created the `TableDetails` segue?

Comment: From table cell or that View Controller?

Comment: Push segue from cell to another ViewController

Answer (score 1):

OK. Let's say you have two viewcontrollers `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.
In `FirstViewController` you have a tableview and of course tableviewcell. In `SecondViewController`you need to display data. 
So in `SecondViewController.h` you need to set a propery of some variable, in this case it is of `id` type `@property (strong, nonatomic) id secDetailItem;`. Synthesize it in `SecondViewController.m` and add a setter method like this

```
-(void)setDetdetailItem:(id)newSecdetailItem{
if (secDetailItem != newSecdetailItem) {
    secDetailItem = newSecdetailItem;

    // Update the view.
     [self configureView];//This method is needed to update view if there are some changes in that view.
}
}
```

So then in `FirstViewController.h` import  `SecondViewController.h` and add property `@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;` then
synthesize. In `FirstViewController.m` file in this delegate method do following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 self.secondViewController.secDetailItem=//set your data should be passed.
```

//Also if you need to push viewcontroller add `pushviewcontroller:SecondViewController`, or use IB to connect tableview cell and SecondViewController together with push method.
}

In this case you will not need to use perform segue. The Setter method will work as soon as you set to the `secDetailItem` something.

Also if you need to update your view in `SecondViewController` add this method to it.

```
- (void)configureView
```

{

```
if (self.secDetailItem) {
    self.textLabel.text=self.secDetailItem;//Data passed from FirstViewController
}
```

}

This is all you need to do. Sorry if it is complicated. Ask any question.

Comment: you can write [secondViewController setSecDetailItem:]; also :)

Comment: yeah is the same.In both cases you call the same method.

Answer (score -1):

It might have something to do with this line:

```
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can delete it if you don't need it.